# mysql db skip inserting existing data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter

I am getting twitter live tweets data, which I am inserting into table. Following is my code.

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
        {   
            $tweet = $arr[$k]['tweet_text'];
            $tweet = escapeshellarg($tweet);
            $tweet = nl2br($tweet);
            $tweet = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$tweet);
            echo " $tweet <br>";
            $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO tweet_data(`tweet`, `city`, `api_time`, `rt_count` ,`sentiment`,`system_time`) VALUES ('".$tweet."','".$city."','".$timestamp."','".$rt_count."','".$sentiment."','".$my_date."')";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }       
        }
```

Problem:

This script get called at every hour. And insert new tweets in table. **It happens that in next hour new tweets are same as in previous hour.**
So it will insert tweets which are already there in the table. I want distinct copy of each tweet in table.

Solution 1:

I select each tweet and compare it with each tweets in the table. IF it matches then skip inserting it.

But gradually my table data will grow to thousands of tweets. Matching each tweets with all tweets in table will take too much time.

Is there any optimized way to do this?

Comment: Add a unique index and use `insert ignore` statement.

Comment: It is more expensive to do comparison on a large set than to remove duplicate data using distinct. So I wouldn't be concerned about having duplicates as much.

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃: thanks dude. mind blowing logic : )